# Regex for start with three alpha and four digits

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have writen an sql statement to retrieve data from Mysql db and I wanted to select data where myId start with three alpha and 4 digits example : `ABC1234K1D2`

```
myId REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}/d{4}'
```

but it gives me empty result(data is available in DB). Could someone point me to correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out :

```
[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}
```

If you want characters to be case insensitive. Try this :

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: @guess_me Looks like MySQL has a pretty limited regex flavour: no `\d` (or `\s`, …). I've expanded my answer.

Comment: @guess_me Though \d is valid in regex, \ is a special character in mysql

Answer (score 3):

In most regex variants the answer would be: `/d` matches a `/` followed by a `d`; I think you want `\d` which matches a digit.

However MySQL has a somewhat limited regex implementation (see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)).

There is no shortcut to character sets like `\d` for any digit.

You need to either use a named character set (`[[:digit:]]`), or just use `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

First, in *regular* regular expressions, to match a digit, you have to use `\d` instead of `/d` (which makes you match `/` followed by `d`).

Then, I had never noticed, but I think `\d` (and the others like `\w`, etc.) don't seem to be available in MySQL. The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) lists the accepted spacial chars, and those generic classes don't appear. You could use `[:digit:]` instead, even if `[0-9]` is quite shorter `;)`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine, just replace `/d` with `\d`.
Final regex: `^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern :

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}
```